# how to solve ubuntu failed to start dbus.service?

Tags: dbus

[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le7lB.jpg)

I don't know how to explain, I'm a new Linux user with the dbus.service problem. Previously I installed openssh sftp in the terminal. Then the desktop display is blank and the cursor doesn't appear, it just looks like...The square is white then I restart the problem appears